# Using AWS EC2 Elastic Network Interface (ENI)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I need to add multiple ENIs to an EC2 instance and would like to use each interface with multiple private and associated elastic IPs. My current EC2 instance allows for multiple network interfaces and multiple EIPs per interface. I have already created and connected the ENIs and assigned additional private and elastic IPs. The problem comes when I try to bind to the EIPs on the ENIs (eth1, eth2...) for outbound traffic. The bind is successful, however the outbound request times out.

I am able to add multiple IPs to the default network interface (eth0) of my EC2 instance and was also able to send outbound traffic using those IPs. It required me executing the command below for each new IP, but it work.

ip addr add dev eth0 xxx.xx.x.xxx/24

Does anyone know how to get this to work? I suspect my route table or some other network configuration needs to be updated, however this is out of my wheelhouse. If there is an automated why or script that I can run that would be even better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer! I found this blog post which had everything I needed to do. Good luck to those who are looking for something similar.

http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2012/06/poor-mans-static-ip-for-ec2-aka-elastic.html