# How to configure two Elastic Network Interfaces for an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-ami, elastic-ip

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance and I am facing a problem to configure two [ENis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) for this instance.

I checked some resources on the net but if I’m right, they do not answer my point.

1. [How do I run my secondary network interface in my Ubuntu EC2 instance?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-secondary-network-interface)
2. [Using the AWS EC2 Elastic Network Interface (ENI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285793/using-aws-ec2-elastic-network-interface-eni)
3. [Associate a public IP address with an EC2 instance with multiple network interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882121/associating-public-ip-with-ec2-instance-with-multiple-network-interfaces)
4. [EC2 with two interfaces (one public and one private)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498558/ec2-with-two-interfaces-one-public-and-one-private)

For network segregation issues, my instance has two network interfaces:

1. The principal without a public IP address. This interface is located in a [private subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-subnets.html) with a dedicated security group, a dedicated network ACL, a dedicated routing table.
2. The secondary network interface is located in a public subnet. There are no restriction due to a security group or a network ACL and the routing table allows external communication via the Internet gateway. It has a private IP and an [elasctic Internet IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) associated with it.

The Linux command `ip a` displays the two interfaces each with its ip address, its CIDR, its broadcast address.

The linux command `ip r` shows the routes that seem correct: the gateway is well the second address of the subnet [see](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/subnet-sizing.html).

These `ip` results are far different from those described in Internet resources where `ip a` does not display the properties of the second ENI.

On the instance, there is a Tomcat server configured without a link address so it listens on all network interfaces. If I try to contact my instance using the Elastic Internet IP, the request does not reach the EC2 instance.

I did a configuration test of the Elastic IP Internet on the primary network interface: it works.

Can someone help to set up on the secondary network interface?